# What's the difference between "arm-linux-user" and "armeb-linux-user"?

Tags: qemu

When compile QEMU from source code, I find in file **configure**, option **--target-list** supports **arm-linux-user** and **armeb-linux-user". I know xx-linux-user is for User Emulation. What is the difference between "arm-linux-user" and "armeb-linux-user"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

armeb-linux-user is for big-endian Linux ARM binaries, and arm-linux-user is for little-endian ARM binaries. If you don't know you want big-endian then you don't want it. (The usual setup for user-mode QEMU uses the host-kernel's binfmt-misc support so it can automatically pick the right -linux-user QEMU binary to run for the guest executable anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

ARMEB = ARM EABI Big-endian

ARMEL = ARM EABI Little-endian

EABI = Embedded Application Binary Interface